# "Advanced" knockout css binding statement doesn't behave exactly as expected

Tags: css, knockout.js

I have a rather lengthy knockout css binding applied to an <li> element.

Under the right scenario in my view model, the class list *could* look like this:

```
<li class="workItem task notRead">
</li>
```

where "workItem" is just a static string, "task" is returned from the "workItemTypeName" computed in my view model and "notRead" is toggled based on properties in my view model.

In the perfect world that exists in my head, I would have been able to combine these three class assignment statements (which work individually):

```
<li class="workItem">
</li>

<li data-bind="css: workItemTypeName">
</li>

<li data-bind="css: { 'notRead': isNotRead }">
</li>
```

into something like this:

```
<li data-bind="css: { 'workItem', workItemTypeName, 'notRead': isNotRead }">
</li>
```

After some wrenching around, I managed to get to this (which works):

```
<li data-bind="attr: { 'class': workItemTypeName + ' ' + ' workItem' }, css: {
'notRead': isNotRead }">
</li>
```

But I just don't *like* it...  Does anybody know if it's possible to combine static, computed and toggled statements into the same css binding?  Or if it's something that has been asked and may be added to knockout in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While @ExplosionPills' solution goes into the right direction, it's still not idiomatic enough, IMHO.

Knockout expects an object of CSS class names and truthy/falsy values or observables (!) in the `css` binding. So just give it one.

```
self.workItemCss = ko.computed(function () {
    var classes = {};
    classes.workItem = true;
    classes.notRead = self.isNotRead;
    classes[ko.unwrap(self.workItemTypeName)] = true;
    return classes;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SHmc8/ (interactive: http://jsfiddle.net/SHmc8/1/)

---

Note that you can also use the `class` attribute and the `css` binding together:

```
<li class="any fixed classes" data-bind="css: workItemCss">
```

so the `classes.workItem = true;` doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than relying on the individual values, you can create a computed method in the ViewModel that returns the value to the binding.  This is more knockout-esque (in my opinion).

```
self.workItemCss = ko.computed(function () {
    return "workItem" + (self.isNotRead() ? " notRead" : "")
        + " " + self.workItemTypeName();
});

<!-- html -->
<li data-bind="css: workItemCss">
```